# What does 'closing the distance between' mean?

Tags: word-usage

In the larger context:

> The poet showed how bad war is. Therefore, closing the distance between the audiences views and the reality of war itself

Comment: *To reconcile*.

Answer (score 5):

In its literal use, *close the distance between* means to move one thing *closer* to a second thing that is at a *distance*:

> *[close](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/close#close-2)*
>
> verb
>
> 4 Gradually get nearer to someone or something:
>
> *[distance](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/distance)*
>
> noun
>
> 1 The length of the space between two points:

In *[The Handbook of Foil Fencing](https://books.google.com/books?id=LNTbAEqeBvkC&pg=PT39&dq=%22close%20the%20distance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aU5hVbaCFsG6sQXXyYHoBg&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22close%20the%20distance%22&f=false)*, by Allan Skipp, the attacker *closes the distance between **himself** and **his opponent***:

> To *close the distance between **you** and **your opponent*** and therefore gain
>   a tactical advantage, you can precede a simple attack with a step
>   forwards used as a foot preparation.

Any metaphorical *distance* can be *closed* metaphorically. In *[The Future of Academic Freedom](https://books.google.com/books?id=J3RJZxuEFs0C&pg=PA178&dq=time%20%22close%20the%20distance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=t0thVaj5Non0yATci4LQBg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=time%20%22close%20the%20distance%22&f=false)*, by Louis Menand, academic freedom *closes the metaphorical distance between **expectation** and **reality***:

> Academic freedom then, is both a guarantor and an exemplification of the ethical practice that constitutes history, the relentless striving to *close the distance between **what is** and **what ought to be***.

In *[The Origins of Cultural Differences and Their Impact on Management](https://books.google.com/books?id=d9LSgA5wRv0C&pg=PA262&dq=literally%20%22close%20the%20distance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=n0FhVbGbAsO_sAWxqICoAw&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=literally%20%22close%20the%20distance%22&f=false)*, by Jack Scarborough a manager attempts to *close the metaphorical distance between **himself** and **his workers***:

> The distance literally divides ***manager*** and **worker**; the worker feels
>   dependent upon the manager yet considers the manager unapproachable
>   and not to be challenged even when the manager seeks *to close the
>   distance*.

In *[Ethics for Adversaries](https://books.google.com/books?id=_QJtjdN8bogC&pg=PA107&dq=time%20%22close%20the%20distance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7EthVYyOCNSyyAT42YOwBQ&ved=0CCAQ6AEwATgU#v=onepage&q=time%20%22close%20the%20distance%22&f=false)*, by Arthur Isak Applbaum, lawyers *close the metaphorical distance between **what a jury might believe** and **what they believe***

> If it helps their case, they do everything within their power and the
>   rules *to close the distance between presenting what **could be believed**
>   and misrepresenting what **they actually believe***.

In the OP, the poet *closes the metaphorical distance between **the audience's view of war** and **the reality of war***.

Answer (score 0):

Here the 'distance' refers to a distance in knowledge or understanding, rather than a spatial distance. So, 'closing the distance' would mean reducing the difference in knowledge, or making all parties come together in terms of understanding. Synonyms: to bring on the same page, to bridge the [knowledge] gap